# best practice for header.php with div?

Tags: php, html

I have a page including a header, which is a div containing two sub-divs.  I am wondering whether it is better to require header.php inside the header div, and have header.php create the two subdivs, or whether I should require header.php at the start of the script and have it create the header div with two sub-divs.

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can do whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "require header.php at the start of the script and have it create the
>   header div with two sub-divs"

this way, it will be easier for you to change anything including that parent div. And its usually a good practice to include a header file before starting any html output. You can do several things with it in future... like writing some statement that require sending of headers (http headers) like start session etc.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to run through the plusses and minuses of both in my head and I could not come out with a clear best.  Will do this, cheers!

Comment: you are welcome :) 
Good luck with your development (y)